# Table (tabular) in wrong section

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

So I have multiple sections and my table is not in the section I've written it in. Does someone know how to fix this kind of problem?

Edit 1: Code is the following

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning,automata, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \pgfplotsset{%
       every tick label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
       every axis label/.append style = {font=\scriptsize}
     }
\KOMAoptions{%
    parskip=full,%
    fontsize=12pt}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother
\chapterfont{\color{Aufgabenfarbe}}  % sets colour of chapters



\definecolor{Aufgabenfarbe}{RGB}{77,77,130}
\globalcolor{Aufgabenfarbe}

\begin{document}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=Aufgabenfarbe}
\tableofcontents


\section{Aufgabe}
Sie haben dieses mit der Schreibmaschine und teilweise von Hand
gesetzte Dokument erhalten, über das auch schon der ein oder andere
Kaffee gelaufen ist. Leider hat niemand mehr das Original.\footnotemark Deswegen
ist es jetzt Ihre Aufgabe, das Dokument mit LaTeX und TikZ neu zu
setzen und eine dazu passende Präsentation mit Beamer zu setzen.

Bearbeiten Sie diese Aufgabe in Zweiergruppen. Ein Student der
Zweiergruppe lädt im Moodle ein Zip-Archiv hoch, das ausschließlich
die Dateien document.tex, literature.bib, presentation.tex und
studenten.txt enthält. Die Datei studenten.txt enthält die Namen und
Matrikelnummern beider Studenten der Zweiergruppe. Die TeX-Dateien
müssen mit folgendem Aufruf unter TeX Live 2019 fehlerfrei übersetzt
werden können: 
\footnotetext{Tatsächlich wurde auch dieses Dokument inklusive der Kaffeeflecken und handschriftlichen Skizzen mit LaTeX gesetzt.}
latexmk -pdf document.tex\\
latexmk -pdf presentation.tex

\subsection{Dokument}
Setzen Sie dieses Dokument mit LaTeX neu. Berücksichtigen Sie dabei die
Grundlagen guter typografischer Gestaltung und reproduzieren Sie \underline{alle
Inhalte und Strukturen} dieses Dokumentes, inklusive dieser
Aufgabenstellung.

\subsubsection{Hinweise}
\begin{itemize}
 \item[--]Setzen Sie Tabellen, Listen und Gliederungselemente mit den
entsprechenden LaTeX-Befehlen.

 \item[--]Setzen Sie die Formeln mit dem Mathematikmodus von LaTeX neu. Verwenden
Sie Theorem-Umgebungen, um Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und Beweise
zu setzen.

 \item[--]Setzen Sie Grafiken mit TikZ neu. Verwenden Sie Farbe, um semantisch
unterschiedliche Elemente sinnvoll zu kennzeichnen.

 \item[--]Verwenden Sie LaTeX, um Gliederungselemente und Beschriftungen
automatisch zu nummerieren.

 \item[--]Verwenden Sie BibTeX oder BibLaTeX, um das Literaturverzeichnis zu
setzen.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Präsentation}
Erstellen Sie mit LaTeX-Beamer eine Präsentation, die
alle Inhalte und Strukturen dieses Dokumentes enthält. Kürzen Sie die
Texte dabei so, dass gute Folien mit hilfreichen Stichpunkten
entstehen. Die Folien müssen alle Gliederungselemente, Tabellen,
Listen, Grafiken, Formeln, Definitionen, Lemmata, Theoreme und
Beweise dieses Dokumentes inklusive dieser Aufgabenstellung
enthalten. Auf das Literaturverzeichnis können Sie in der
Präsentation verzichten.

\section{Inhalte}
In diesem Abschnitt des Dokumentes finden Sie verschiedene
Inhaltselemente, deren Umsetzung mit LaTeX Sie im Rahmen der
Vorlesung kennen gelernt haben.
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  decision/.style={diamond,draw, text width=4.5em, text badly centered,
    inner sep=1pt},
  io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
    minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, 
    draw=black,trapezium stretches=true},
  block/.style={minimum width=2cm,draw},
  forked/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}},
  node distance=1cm and 2cm
    ]
\node [io] (a){technical device};
\node [below=of a,decision] (does) {Does it move?};
\node [below right= of does,decision] (si) {Should it?}; 
\node [below left = of does,decision] (si2) {Should it?};
\node [below left=1cm and 1cm of si2,block] (wd40) {WD-40};
\node [below right=1cm and 1cm of si,block] (dt) {duct tape};
\path (wd40) -- node [block] (ok) {OK} (dt);

\draw[-stealth,semithick]    (a) edge (does);
\draw[-stealth,semithick,forked,nodes={above,font=\sffamily}]
    (does) edge node {yes}(si.north)
    (does) edge  node {no} (si2)
    (si2) edge node {yes}  (wd40)
    (si2) edge node {no}  (ok.160)
    (si) edge node {yes}  (ok.20)
    (si) edge node {no}  (dt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Abbildung 1: Ablaufdiagramm der Ingenieurwissenschaft}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex,shorten >=1pt,auto]
\node[state] (s_0) at(2,0) {$s_0$};
\node[state] (s_1) [above right=of s_0] {$s_1$};
\node[state] (s_2) [below right=of s_1] {$s_2$};
\node[state](s_3) [right=of s_2] {$s_3$};
\node[state] (s_4) [above right=of s_3] {$s_4$};
\node[] (correction) [below = of s_4] {};
\node[state] (s_5) [below right= of correction] {$s_5$};
\node[state](s_6) [right=of s_5] {$s_6$};
\path[->] (s_1) edge node {0} (s_2)
(s_3) edge node {0} (s_5);
\path[->,dashed](s_6) edge[bend right=15] node [swap,pos=.3] {$last_3(w,1)=1$} (s_1);
\draw (0,0)node[left]{2}--(s_0)--(s_2)--(s_3)--(13,0);
\draw (0,0 |- s_1)node[left]{1}--(s_1)--(s_4)--(s_4-| 13,0);
\draw (0,0 |- s_5)node[left]{3}--(s_5)--(s_6)--(s_6-| 13,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Ausführung w eines verteilten Systems. Der Zustand in
Position 6 gehört zu Agent $A_3$. In diesem Zustand ist
Position 1 die letzte Position von Agent $A_1$
, die Agent
$A_3$ kennt.}
\end{figure}\\

\subsection{Abbildungen und Tabellen}
Abbildungg 1 zeigt das Engineering Flow Chart. Es handelt sich um ein
Ablaufdiagramm, das einen Arbeitsablauf visualisiert. zeigt die
Ausführung eines verteilten Systems mit den Agenten 1, 2 und 3, während
verschiedene Sinus-Schwingungen zeigt.

Von den Abbildungen kommen wir nun zu einigen Tabellen. zeigt die
Verkaufspreise von Mücken, Gnus, Emus und Gürteltieren. Der tiefere Sinn
dieser Tabelle erschließt sich vermutlich nur dem Leser, der sie aus dem
LaTeX-Handbuch oder der Dokumentation des Pakets booktabs kennt. Dem
gegenüber zeigt die Synchronsprecher eines Filmes.
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      width=16cm, height=5cm,
      xmin=0, xmax=10.2,
      ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
      axis lines = left,
    ]
    \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {sin(deg(x))} node[right] {$\sin{(x)}$};
    \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue] {cos(deg(x))} node[right] {$\cos{(x)}$};
    \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {sin(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\sin{(2x)}$};
    \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {cos(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\cos{(2x)}$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Artikel} \\
\hline
Tiere& Beschreibungg &pREIS \\
\hline
Mücke & pro Gramm  &13,65 \\
""&pro Stück& 0,01\\
Gnu & ausgestopft & 92,50 \\
Emu & ausgestopft& 33,33   \\
Gülteltier & gefroren &8,99 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Übersicht über die Preise sehr verschiedener Tiere in
unterschiedlichen Darreichungsformen.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}\\
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|  }
\hline
Rolle& Stimme 1961/1962 &Stimme 1976/1977 \\
\hline
Lukas & Walter Schellmann  &Manfred Jenning \\
Jim Knopf&Elisabeth Göttlerr& 0,01\\
Gnu & ausgestopft & Winfried Küppers\\
Erzähler&Manfred Jenning&Sepp Wäsche\\
König Alfons&Max Bößl&Gerhard Jentsch\\
Herr Ärmel&Günter Knecht&Arno Bergler\\
Frau Waas&Rose Oehmichen&Rose Oehmichen
\end{tabular}
\caption{Synchronsprecher der Verfilmung von Jim Knopf und Lukas der
Lokomotivführer durch den Hessischen Rundfunk.}
\label{tab:template}
\end{table}


\subsection{Quellen}

Edsger Dijkstra war ein niederländischer Informatiker, der in seiner
Dissertation eine Programmiersprache für die Electrologica X1
entwickelte. Die X1 war ein Digital-Computer, der in den 1950er Jahren
in den Niederlanden produziert wurde. Neben seiner Dissertation sei hier
noch auf ein nicht veröffentlichtes Paper und ein Beitrag in einem
Sammelband verwiesen.

Amir Pnueli war ein israelischer Informatiker, der wegweisende
Verdienste um die Einführung der temporalen Logik in die Informatik
geleistet hat.

Der IBM 701 war der erste für wissenschaftliche Zwecke bestimmte Rechner
von IBM. Sein Speedcoding System wird von John Backus im Journal-Artikel
beschrieben. The C Programming Language ist das erste Buch über die
Programmiersprache C.

\subsection{Quelltext}

Bubblesort ist ein Algorithmus, der vergleichsbasiert eine Liste von
Elementen sortiert:
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java]

1 void bubblesrt(int array[]) {
2    int n = array.length;
3    int k;
4    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
5        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
6            k = i + 1;
7            if (array[i] > array[k]) {
8                swapNumbers(i, k, array);
9            }
10        }
11    }
12 }
\end{lstlisting}
\subsection{Theoreme und Mathematik}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{lemma}(p-q-Forrmel).{
Mit f(x) = x+px+q gilt $f(x_0) = 0$ genau dann,
wenn
$x_0 = -\frac{p}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{p}{2}^{2}-q}$
}
\end{lemma}

Mit gilt genau dann, wenn

oder

Die p-q-Formel ergibt sich aus durch quadratische
Ergänzung.

Eine Definition ist die Bestimmung eines Begriffs.

hat keine reelle Nullstelle.

Folgt unmittelbar mit Lemma .

Darüber hinaus gilt .


\end{document}
```

Edit: Had to set the tables to `h` (here) instead of `t` (top) but the last one is still in another section.

Comment: Are you in two-column mode?

Comment: a tikzpicture will just appear where you place it in the source.  Perhaps you placed it in a `figure`, the only thing a `figure` environment does is mark the region to   latex as a block that can be moved to another page to help with page breaking. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: Checked the figures all end right after the tikzpicture.

Comment: two-column mode?

Comment: unrelated but don't do `\end{figure}\\ ` the `figure` is a floating environment not in the main document flow but you are forcing  `\\  ` at a fixed point in the document unrelated to where the figure is placed (and also there should never be a blank line after `\\ ` )

Comment: just did it for the sake of solving the problem

Comment: Start by reading Frank Mittelbach [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111mitt-float.pdf)

Comment: well \clearpage did its job thanks

Comment: @RackCloud For that you can use also `\FloatBarrier`  (obvious function, is not it?) from `placeins` package. The problem, however, is that whatever you use to fix positions of tables and figure floats, sometimes this will left horrendous gaps when float have not enough space. Better, read the above link, and the keep in mind that `\ref{}` and `\labels{}` exist just  because not always tables and figures can remain close to the related text. No one likes tables moving from the page that you want, but avoid it at the cost of leaving half empty pages is worse.